# Inconsistent import behavior for a wide and deep table

Tags: powerbi

We have a backend table in SingleStore database, which is being imported in Power BI. The table is having 85 columns and data exists for multiple dates. Each day is having ~14 million rows (which is like 500 MB). We have added some simple power queries (e.g. filter, concatenation etc.) on this. When imported for multiple dates 4 or more, then we can see data loss. Means not all the data for all the dates are not being imported correctly (we can see count mismatch). This issue we are seeing when we are importing all 85 columns from the backend table, but when we are restricting to limited columns i.e., 10-12, then data import is proper.

Question is - Is it a limitation with Power BI with deep and wide tables ? Is there any possible work around for this issue ?

Comment: Is this in Power BI Desktop or Power BI Service (published)?

Comment: It is with Power BI service

Comment: Power BI Service has a 1GB limit on Shared capacity (“Power BI Pro”), and a default 10GB on Premium. Which are you on? If you are hitting the limit, then consider using DirectQuery instead of Import.

Comment: We are in Power BI premium and with P2 capacity. So shared capacity shouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: See [Large semantic models in Power BI Premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-large-models) - enable "Large semantic model storage format", and at the bottom, "Checking semantic model size" to see how big it is. Do you get any refresh errors or messages in the Refresh history? If not then the issue may be with the connector or the datasource.

Comment: We already changed that to "Large semantic model storage format", but that doesn't change anything. But our further testing revels if we remove "text" data type columns then the refresh bringing all the data correctly. We are using SingleStore driver to connect to Power BI, not sure if it is driver issue or not.

Comment: removing "text" type columns is not bringing all data every time correctly. We are still observing data loss.

Answer (score 0):

When importing a table with 85 columns and 14 million rows every day, the amount and complexity of the data could exceed Power BI's capabilities, resulting in data loss or incomplete imports. This is especially true when data modifications (such as filters and concatenation) are used, as they increase processing burden. Several factors can influence Power BI's performance, such as:

> Power BI has a maximum dataset size restriction (1 GB for Pro users
> and up to 400 GB for Premium per dataset). The processing power (CPU,
> RAM) of the system running Power BI Desktop, or the capacity of the
> Power BI service, might affect the ability to manage huge datasets.

To overcome the issue you are facing

> Use Power BI's incremental refresh strategy to import only new or
> updated data after the first load. Limit the amount of columns
> imported into Power BI to only those that are absolutely required for
> your research. Instead of loading data into Power BI, use DirectQuery
> mode to retrieve data straight from SingleStore. This method does not
> import data into Power BI; instead, queries are executed on the
> database.

Comment: Yes, we already have incremental refresh in place. But this is the first refresh after publishing the dataset in the PBI service, where we want to refresh for 30 business days. We are facing problem in this activity only.